# How to find the sum of the array properties' values of objects from the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of countries and populations. How can I withdraw the amount of population in all countries?

```js
[
  { name: 'Poland', population: 42 000 000},
  { name: 'Belarus', population: 9 500 000},
  { name: 'Moldova', population: 3 500 000},
  { name: 'Switzerland', population: 8 400 000}
]

function calculateAverageCountryPopulation(countries) {

}
```

The sum of the array elements is not difficult. But I don't know how to do this task.

```js
var arr = [3, 2, 5, 6];

function arraySum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
arraySum(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculateAverageCountryPopulation(countries) {
  return countries.map(x => x.population).reduce((acc, y) => acc + y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working - can you give me a link to read more about this solution? Thank you!

Comment: This is not the average.

Comment: @Bibberty correct, the question asked for the sum

Comment: @PerryNomad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Comment: Yes, but the the function name .... :)

Comment: @Bibberty lol, and here we also learn the importance of properly naming your functions!

Comment: Yea you both are right! the sum is - understand for me - and how to calculate average population of the countries?

Comment: @PerryNomad take the sum and divide it by the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

Use a reduce and divide.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Poland', population: 42000000},
  { name: 'Belarus', population: 9500000},
  { name: 'Moldova', population: 3500000},
  { name: 'Switzerland', population: 8400000}
]
const calculateAverageCountryPopulation = (countries) => countries.reduce((a,{ population: p}) => a+=p,0)/countries.length;

console.log(calculateAverageCountryPopulation(data));
```